# How to pass a string to a post call, using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm implementing a jira api call : 
[Add watcher to a JIRA issue.](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/#api/2/issue-addWatcher)

It takes a `String` parameter instead of `JSON`.

I'm using [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/).

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

What should be my value of data if the jira documentation says I need to pass just String but `requests.post` method only accepts JSON?

Comment: Change `json=data` to `data=data`?

Comment: Isnt data also a key, value paired input type ref: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply do:

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

According to the [official docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

> There are many times that you want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a `string` instead of a `dict`, that data will be posted directly.